# Como mudar botões de lugar dinamicamente usando Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, grid

Eu sei que esse código tem muita repetição e pretendo "enxugar" ele posteriormente. Por agora, quero entender como faço para mudar a posição dos botões em Tkinter de forma dinâmica. A solução que pensei inicialmente foi usar `grid` para posicionar os botões, usando variáveis nos argumentos `row` e `column`, e então criar uma função que altere o valor dessas variáveis. Contudo, essa "solução" não está funcionando. Segue código abaixo para replicação do problema:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random


def change_position():
    new_row = button_6.grid_info().get("row")
    new_col = button_6.grid_info().get("column")
    button_6.grid(row=button_empty.grid_info().get("row"), column=button_empty.grid_info().get("column"))
    button_empty.grid(row=new_row, column=new_col)

class Single_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('5-Sliding Block')
        self.resizable(False, False)

root = Single_window()

button_f1 = tk.Frame(root)
button_4 = ttk.Button(button_f1, text = '4')
button_4.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_5 = ttk.Button(button_f1, text = '5')
button_5.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_6 = ttk.Button(button_f1, text = '6', command = change_position)
button_6.grid(row= 0, column= 2)
button_f1.pack(side = 'top')

button_f2 = tk.Frame(root)
button_7 = ttk.Button(button_f2, text = '7')
button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8 = ttk.Button(button_f2, text = '8')
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_empty = ttk.Button(button_f2)
button_empty.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_f2.pack(side = 'top')

root.mainloop()
```

Meu objetivo é criar um jogo de "Sliding blocks" de ordem 6. Ver exemplo nesse [site](https://www.helpfulgames.com/subjects/brain-training/sliding-puzzle.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara ficou legal o que você fez mas tem alguns erros
primeiramente, quando você cria um frame, meio que ele tem o seu proprio grid, e no seu código você acaba criando dois para separar a linha de cima da de baixo

```
# instanciação dos frames
button_f1 = tk.Frame(root)
button_f2 = tk.Frame(root)
```

por isso que quando você clicava no botão que tinha o script de alterar a posição acabava criando mais linhas dentro do frame.
Outra coisa seria você utilizar as funções a partir da classe que você criou, então criar métodos para criar os botões e gerenciar a posição dele. Eu fiz um exemplo de como poderia ser para ficar mais fácil de entender

```
class Single_window(tk.Tk):
    # Parametros para criar o objeto, como o exemplo que você passou o link
    def __init__(self, linhas, colunas):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('5-Sliding Block')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.Linhas = linhas
        self.Colunas = colunas
        # talvez uma lista com os botoes que forem instanciados para você fazer alguma validação futura
        # como ver se a pessoa concluiu o desafio
        self.botoes = []
        # uma variavel para guardar a linha e coluna que esta livre no momento
        self.PosicaoLivre = [linhas-1, colunas-1]
        print (self.PosicaoLivre)
        # Gerar os botões a partir da denifição do frame
        numeracaoAtual = 0
        for x in range (0, self.Linhas):
            for y in range (self.Colunas):
                # aqui é uma validação para não criar o ultimo botao
                if (y == self.Colunas - 1 and x == self.Linhas - 1):
                    continue
                self.GerarBotao(numeracaoAtual, x, y)
                numeracaoAtual += 1

    def GerarBotao(self, numeracaoBotao, linha, coluna):
        botao = ttk.Button(self, text = numeracaoBotao)
        botao.grid(row = linha, column = coluna)
        # esse lambda é uma "gambiarra" para fazer com que voce possa jogar o próprio objeto no command
        # caso voce tente por o objeto diretamente sem o lambda, a função é chamada na crialçao do objeto
        # logo o clique não funciona
        botao.configure(command = lambda botaoObj=botao: self.TrocarPosicao(botaoObj))
        self.botoes.append(botao)

    def TrocarPosicao(self, botao):
        # pega as linhas do botão que foi apertado
        linhaBotaoPressionado = botao.grid_info().get("row")
        colunaBotaoPressionado = botao.grid_info().get("column")
        # a primeira validação é ver se o botão esta na horizontal ou vertical em relação a posição livre
        if self.PosicaoLivre[0] == linhaBotaoPressionado or self.PosicaoLivre[1] == colunaBotaoPressionado:
            # a segunda validação verifica se o botão esta a pelo menos 1 espaço na grid de distancia do espaço livre
            if abs(self.PosicaoLivre[0] - linhaBotaoPressionado) == 1 or abs(self.PosicaoLivre[1] - colunaBotaoPressionado) == 1:
                # guarda o valor temporário da posição livre
                posicaoLivreTemp = [linhaBotaoPressionado, colunaBotaoPressionado]
                # coloca o botão na posição livre do frame
                botao.grid(row = self.PosicaoLivre[0], column = self.PosicaoLivre[1])
                self.PosicaoLivre = posicaoLivreTemp

root = Single_window(10,10)

root.mainloop()
```

outra coisa, creio que seja melhor escrever as coisas em portugues porque desta forma vc acaba se encontrando muito melhor no código :)